# create a sql server job to fill a table from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, ssms-2017

I have a 2 tables, I want to set a job for filling table 1 with some data in table 2. but there are some other columns in table1 that are not in table2. these cloumns have constant value.
for example:
table1:
name, date,number (random)
table 2:
name,date

i wanna put name and date from table 2 into table 1 automatically. but I dont know how to fill third coulmun.

thanks

Comment: What would the random number be based on? and can you give an example.

Comment: It's not important. some of them are 0 or 1, and the other are forexample between 1 and 1000. my question is how to fill a table with some constant value and others from a existing table?

Answer (score 0):

> my question is how to fill a table with some constant value and others from a existing table?

Just like that:

```
insert into table1(name, date, num)
select name, date, 1 from table2
```

This assigns a constant value of `1` to column `num` in every row that is copied from the source.

If you want something else, say an auto-incrementing counter:

```
insert into table1(name, date, num)
select name, date, row_number() over(order by (select null)) from table2
```

If you had a `default` on the target column that you wanted to rely on, you would just ignore the column in the statement:

```
insert into table1(name, date)
select name, date from table2
```

Comment: Thank you. but table2 has not constant value. I want to fill my table1 column with some data from table 2 . the other table1 columns are constant and I have to fill them myself! there aren't in table 2

Comment: I have to fill some columns with table 2 values and the others with constant value ( for example value from 1 to 1000)

Comment: @AfsanRezaei: that's what the first query does. I extended my answer with another example.

Comment: @AfsanRezaei Do you understand the meaning of "constant"? It does not vary or mutate or change (e.g., 1 to 1000). Now would be a good time to provide a simple example of a few rows you want to insert and what the content of those inserted rows should be after insertion.